# Creating a form and displaying entry data as a table

Tags: plugins, forms

I'm brand new to Wordpress, but I have experience in web-development.

I'm trying to create a form with custom fields. When submitting the form, I'd like to append the entries of the form to a table. I'm not sure where or what to look for.

I saw that using a combination of Ninja Forms + Conductor, it is possible to achieve this, but sadly, due to its cost, I cannot get access to Conductor.

What is a way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your db table. Example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).
2. Generate your [wp_list_table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) admin page. Generator is [here](http://projects.tareq.co/wp-generator/index.php).
3. Insert your form values to your db table. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26582772/7646822).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll use PHP my admin to create a table. Is there anything I should be aware  when doing this instead of creating it programmatically.

Comment: No just create table. But you should care of $_POST fileds. I suggest use sanitize. https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: Okay thanks. How about the other part of the question. Any free plugins I can use to display the information of the database table in a HTML table ? Or do I have to make that myself?